# On an EMR android tablet (wacom stylus) can touch events be handled silmultaneously to touch events?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, touch, stylus-pen

This is a duplicate to a question left unanswered and probably un-understood from another OP.

On an Adroid tablet equipped with wacom's EMR stylus technology, while detecting touch events, a pointerEvent can hold the changes of multiple pointer (like multiple fingers on the screen) (using jetpack compose and Kotlin here).

However, once the stylus is used on the screen, the capacitive touch detection doesn't seem to report anymore and only stylus events are sent until the stylus is lifted.
And even once the stylus is lifted, already-down fingers won't trigger any events until they are lifted and touching again.

Is there any low level way to detect a combination of touch and stylus events to allow for complex use cases ?